# ARM - non continuous subaccount

Tags: acumatica

According to the list of new/updated features in acumatica it mentions the following: "Specify multiple, non-continuous ranges in the data source for accounts, subaccounts,and branches in the general ledger engine."

However from what I'm seeing, this doesn't seem to apply to subaccounts.

For example in my situation, the first segment of the subaccount defines the "region".

When defining my Unit sets what I need to do is the following:

Central Region - (subacct segment AB and DE)
-   Sub1 (AB)
-   Sub2 (DE)

North Region (subacct segment BC)

In the Data Source, I can only specify a single "Start" and "End" subaccount which uses all in between.

Is it possible to have the "Central Region" be a summary of all the child nodes OR can I specify i want ONLY subaccts AB, DE for "Central Region"

In FRx you can do this where the "Folder" or "Parent" is a summary of the children items underneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible, but by default the user interface will not allow you to enter the string in such a way, due to the segmented nature of the subaccount field. You can, however, customize the field so that it no longer behaves as a segmented editor. To do that, you need to create a PXCacheExtension on RMDataSourceGL which will override the StartSub/EndSub attributes. The class looks like that:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.CS;

namespace PX.Objects.CS
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class RMDataSourceGL : PXCacheExtension<RMDataSource>
    {
        [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Start Sub.")]
        public virtual string StartSub { get; set; }

        [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "End Sub.")]
        public virtual string EndSub { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Once the customization is in place, you can put non-contiguous ranges in the StartSub/EndSub fields. Please note that the segmented key separator (usually it's '-') should **not** be part of the ranges. For example, assuming you want to include all subaccounts between US-00-00-00-000 and US-99-99-99-999 AND all the CA- accounts, you would put the following in the StartSub field: US?????????,CA?????????. You could also express it differently: US000000000-US999999999,CA000000000-CA999999999. The syntax is documented in the 5.0 release notes, and is the same for accounts.

Comment: Gabriel,   Perfect as always.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a secondary Comment for those who might be reading this, I also found that it is possible to make a Parent folder summarize the children.  For Example:

1. CE - Central Region

   - AB - Sub1
   - DE - Sub2

Instead of specifying a Data Source for "CE", specify a Value of

```
    =@AB+@DE
```

Comment: But please note that to generate this ARM report, system has to make twice as may calculations - each unit in the unit set gets generated as a separate report in memory. It's useful only if you need the ability to drill-down to specific regions.

Comment: Thank you for that reminder....  In my case, this is a true statement (drill-down) but good to know.